# Python: Migration MongoDB to DynamoDB - Float Error

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

I'm starting to use Python in my daily chores, I found a problem I can't solve. With this script, modifying only the name of the collection (MongoDB) and the name of the table (DynamoDB), the whole process runs very well in other collections.

In one collection (example below), the script does not perform so well, because in the collection there is floating data, such as geolocalization data

```
import sys

# Mongo
import pprint
from pymongo import MongoClient
Client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = Client["developer"]
collection = db["geolocation"]

# Dynamo
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('geolocation')


# migrate
count = 0
with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for migrate in collection.find():
        del migrate['__v']
        del migrate['_id']

        batch.put_item(Item= migrate)

        # To show process
        count += 1
        print(str(collection.count()) + '::' + str(count))
```

The error that occurred is: **float types are not supported. Use Decimal types instead**.

I need to help to create a def that scans the object and replace the value of float to decimals. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

DynamoDB expects Decimal format for floats when the item is uploaded via boto3.

You need to replace all floats with Decimal in the dictionary from MongoDB.

First, convert the python dictionary back to JSON

```
import json
migrate_json = json.dumps(migrate)
```

Then, parse the JSON back to python dictionary with floats stored as Decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal
migrate = json.loads(migrate_json, parse_float=Decimal)
```

Now the upload will work

```
batch.put_item(Item=migrate)
```

Answer (score 4):

This def fixes the problem

```
def replace_float(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for i in xrange(len(obj)):
            obj[i] = replace_float(obj[i])
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k in obj.iterkeys():
            obj[k] = replace_float(obj[k])
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, float):
        if obj % 1 == 0:
            return int(obj)
        else:
            return Decimal(str(obj))
    else:
        return obj
```

So, replace...

```
newItem=replace_float(migrate)
batch.put_item(Item=newItem)
```